# asp.net mvc razor cannot pass counter increment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

i am increment i in this code which i am not able to parse. what is wrong with i in the code below?

```
  @{        
            int i=0;
            }
@foreach (var item in Model.PortServiceTariffIncluded)
{


         <tr id="@("sp" + item.ServiceId)">
         <td>@item.ServiceName     <input type="hidden" name="QuotationDetailList[i].ServiceId" value="@item.ServiceId" /></td>
         <td>@item.ServiceCriteria</td>
         <td>@item.ItemBasis</td>
          <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, ViewBag.CurrencyDd as SelectList) <input type ="text" id="Amount@i" name="QuotationDetailList[i].Amount" /></td>
         <td><input type="hidden" value="@item.ServiceId" class="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" /><input type ="button" id="@item.ServiceId" name="btnremove" value="Remove" class="clsremove" /></td>
         </tr>
         i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following, instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PortServiceTariffIncluded.Select((value, i) => new { i, value })
{
     <tr id="@("sp" + item.value.ServiceId)">
         <td>@item.ServiceName <input type="hidden" name="QuotationDetailList[item.i].ServiceId" value="@item.value.ServiceId" /></td>
         <td>@item.value.ServiceCriteria</td>
         <td>@item.value.ItemBasis</td>
         <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, ViewBag.CurrencyDd as SelectList) <input type ="text" id="Amount@item.i" name="QuotationDetailList[item.i].Amount" /></td>
         <td><input type="hidden" value="@item.value.ServiceId" class="serviceslist" name="serviceslist" /><input type ="button" id="@item.value.ServiceId" name="btnremove" value="Remove" class="clsremove" /></td>
     </tr>
}
```

Basically, this causes your `item` variable to be an object consisting of an iterator (`item.i`) and the actual item (`item.value`).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would set a variable to contain your `QuotationDetailList` :

```
@{ var QuotationDetailList = Model.QuotationDetailList;}
```

Then, use a `for` here instead of a `foreach` :

```
@for (var ListIndex = 0; ListIndex < Model.PortServiceTariffIncluded.Count(); ListIndex++)
```

Now you can reference items using your variable and the index :

```
<td>@QuotationDetailList[ListIndex].ServiceName     <input type="hidden" name="@QuotationDetailList[ListIndex].ServiceId" value="@QuotationDetailList[ListIndex].ServiceId" /></td>
```